# Running Tomcat7 at port 443 in Windows

Tags: java, security, tomcat, https, tomcat7

In https mode, by default Tomcat runs in port 8443, and because of this reason the port number has to be included in the url. eg: https://www.xyzdomain.com:8443/login

In order to get rid of the port number from the URL, I think I need to run Tomcat at 443. This is snippet from my **server.xml**

```
<!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
     and responses are returned. Documentation at :
     Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
     Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
     APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
     Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
-->
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />

<!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
     This connector uses the BIO implementation that requires the JSSE
     style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
     OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
     documentation -->

<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           redirectPort="443" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="C:\Users\certificate\www_abc_com.jks" keystorePass="password" />
```

I have tried many things including following with server.xml but could not make tomcat to run in port 443 on Windows.

1. Changed first Connector port from 8443 to 443.
2. Added redirectPort=443
3. Added another connector port with number 443.

Some people have suggested to start tomcat as root (I right-clicked and run as admin the start.bat file). Some suggested to add the redirection in IP Tables, but I am on Windows.

Comment: Not programming related. You should find plenty of information on the combination of Apache httpd with tomcat: Use Apache in front of Tomcat - this way Apache serves port 443 and handles https, then forwards the request handling to Tomcat

Comment: Thank you Olaf, this is what I had been thinking and you confirmed. I will give it a shot.